# React Native listview with different type of components

Tags: listview, gridview, react-native

I am developing a react native application. On its homepage I need to show some posts like video, audio, images, blogs, articles etc. I am confused as how to achieve that . How can I make a list or grid view with different type of components, mix of audio , video, images. From backend we will add a image or video or audio or a blog and a new post will be created in the list.Also I want to add that new post to the beginning and not at the end.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FlatList` to do this. It's so easy to use and its performance is good and it is recommended by React-Native (look at [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)). 
This is a simple example of using `FlatList` you can handle your list items in a separated component or function and pass it in the `renderItem` prop of `FlatList`. You can see the full document of `FlatList` in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/flatlist.html):

```
  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    if (item.type === 'video') {
      <MyVideo item={item}/>
    } else if (item.type === 'image') {
      <MyImage item={item}/>
    } else if ...
      ...
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={dataList}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! .Sorry, But I am confused about flatlist , not able to understand properly. What is dataList Passed to data and from where do I pass type of the item?

Comment: I assume the `dataList` is the list of your posts and I assume that your post object has a type property that you can detect the type of your post by using this and choose the appropriate UI component for each post (for example: `<ImageComponent/>` or `<VideoComponent/>`).

Comment: `_renderItem` is the function that return the appropriate UI component for your posts. You should define your own UI component for each type of your posts.

Comment: I do not have any api's yet so What i will do is add buttons for different posts and then on clicking a button a new post will be added to the flatlist , is it possible to create a empty flatlist and then create posts on click of a button ?

Comment: You can store your data array in your state and by pressing the button add a new post to your array and use `setState` to apply the new array to state and it causes to render the component and new post will be added to your list.

Comment: Can you update your code with this array code , It will be easy for me to understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152499/discussion-between-paras-watts-and-vahid-boreiri).

Comment: Can you please check I have sent you a message

Comment: Please check my message